# PostgreSQL 'NOT IN' and subquery

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I'm trying to execute this query:

```
SELECT mac, creation_date 
FROM logs 
WHERE logs_type_id=11
AND mac NOT IN (select consols.mac from consols)
```

But I get no results. I tested it, and I know that there is something wrong with the syntax. In MySQL such a query works perfectly. I've added a row to be sure that there is one `mac` which does not exist in the `consols` table, but still it isn't giving any results.

Comment: Is the `consols.mac` column `NULL` or `NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

When using NOT IN you should ensure that none of the values are NULL:

```
SELECT mac, creation_date 
FROM logs 
WHERE logs_type_id=11
AND mac NOT IN (
    SELECT mac
    FROM consols
    WHERE mac IS NOT NULL -- add this
)
```

Comment: Note: the `WHERE mac IS NOT NULL` clause in the subquery is not needed, since `In(...)` always removes NULLs (and duplicates). Because a set cannot contain NULLs

Comment: @wildplasser I dunno about that. It wasn't working for me, until I added the `IS NOT NULL`. The nested `SELECT` was returning a few `NULLS`, and that was tripping up the `IN(SELECT...)`.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate an explanation as to why the `IS NOT NULL` causes this to work.

Comment: It appears that using `NULL` in a `NOT IN` clause doesn't work because a comparison to `NULL` is neither true nor false. http://www.sqlbadpractices.com/using-not-in-operator-with-null-values/

Comment: I'll add my voice to the group that notices that without "is not null" the query returns no rows, but when adding "is not null" I get the desired values. Great answer.

Comment: The query will return no rows in absence of the `is not null` if the subquery produces no matching values and at least one `null` value. From [section 9.22](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-NOTIN) of the current (version 10) PostgreSQL manual: "[…] if there are no equal right-hand values and at least one right-hand row yields null, the result of the NOT IN construct will be null, not true."

Answer (score 36):

When using NOT IN, you should also consider NOT EXISTS, which handles the null cases silently. See also [PostgreSQL Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN)

```
SELECT mac, creation_date 
FROM logs lo
WHERE logs_type_id=11
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM consols nx
  WHERE nx.mac = lo.mac
  );
```

Comment: Also note a huge performance loss when using `NOT EXISTS` vs `... NOT IN`

Comment: @IcanDivideBy0 In most cases they generate the same query plan. Have you tested it?

Comment: There's also a performance gain in using NOT IN instead of NOT EXISTS, in case of subqueries. See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN

Comment: @Gerbrand your link seems to indicate you gain performance if using EXISTS instead of IN. Contrary to what you said....

Answer (score 13):

You could also use a LEFT JOIN and IS NULL condition:

```
SELECT 
  mac, 
  creation_date 
FROM 
  logs
    LEFT JOIN consols ON logs.mac = consols.mac
WHERE 
  logs_type_id=11
AND
  consols.mac IS NULL;
```

An index on the "mac" columns might improve performance.