# "NOT IN" subquery with a leading wildcard

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, wildcard

I have two tables:

Table `tablefoo` contains a column `fulldata`.
Table `tablebar` contains a column `partialdata`.

I want find a list of `tablefoo.fulldata` that do NOT have partial matches in `tablebar.partialdata`.

The following provides a list of `tablefoo.fulldata` with partial matches in `tablebar`, but I want the negative of this.

```
select fulldata from tablefoo
where fulldata like any (select '%' || partialdata from tablebar);
```

This lists every record in `partialdata`:

```
select fulldata from tablefoow
where partialdata not in (select '%' || partialdata from tablebar);
```

Any idea how to get only the results `tablefoo.fulldata` that do not contain matches to a leading wildcarded `tablebar.partialdata`?

I found this link:  [PostgreSQL 'NOT IN' and subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463043/postgresql-not-in-and-subquery) which seems like it's headed down the right path, but I'm not getting it to work with the wildcard.

Sure, I could write a script to pull this out of psql and do the comparisons, but it would be much nicer to handle this all as part of the query.

Comment: Your version of Postgres, the table definitions (`\d tbl`in psql) and sample data would be in order. Ideally a test case, for instance on sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: Postgres version is 9.1.  I'll look at adding an example to sqlfiddle.com.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT fulldata
FROM   tablefoo f
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   tablebar b
   WHERE  f.fulldata LIKE ('%' || b.partialdata)
   );
```

Comment: @thatguy: I see that kordirko already posted the same but deleted it after you claimed it did not work. Well, it **should** work. Or the question is wrong somehow.

Comment: I was bummed it was deleted as I was hoping to use it as a starting point for comments.  I'm working through my data to make sure there isn't something in that tripping everything.  Thanks for your response.  I'll post back in a bit.

Comment: It's not you.  It's me.  It worked the 4th time I unfoobarred it.  Thanks to kordirko for the original answer and to Erwin for pointing out how I didn't make good use of the original answer.